# selecting an element with no id and name from the typeahead list using css selector

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have to select an element from the auto-complete list.The item has no id and no name.
The following are the details of the inspected element:

```
<div class="abc-suggestion">
<p class="" style="white-space: normal;">
XYZ 
<span class="pull-right"/>
```

The css selector

`.abc-suggestion` takes me to

```
<div class="abc-suggestion">
```

and

`.tt-suggestion>p` to

```
<p class="" style="white-space: normal;">
```

How can I select the element from the auto-complete list 'XYZ'

(I required to select an element for automating the application using selenium webdriver)

Comment: Add a small HTML snippet, otherwise we will just be guessing. If the only distinctive feature of the element is the text within it, you may need to use XPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in Selenium if I understand your question but I don't want to guess. Can you please show the exact html markup for the `<div class="abc-suggestion">` and be clear in what you're trying to select within it? 
Here's my understanding of your question:

1. You want to select just the text "XYZ" and you say it has NO id and NO name, but yet, I see "XYZ" wrapped in a P tag. Furthermore, where does the P tag closes?
2. Please be clear, I think I know what your problem is, it's a simple fix if you show the whole html snippet FOR the `<div class="abc-suggestion">` and where that div closes; again just the html code for that div only and what you're tying to select within it should be enough for me or someone else to help you.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
List<WebElement> paragraphList=null;
paragraphList=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.tt-suggestions p")); 
String abcText=paragraphList.get(0).getText();
String xyzText=paragraphList.get(1).getText();
```

Comment: ' <span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none; right: auto;">
   <div class="tt-dataset-destinations"><span class="tt-suggestions" style="display: block;">
<div class="tt-suggestion">
<p class="" style="white-space: normal;">
ABC 
<span class="pull-right"></span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="tt-suggestion">
<p class="" style="white-space: normal;">
XYZ 
<span class="pull-right"></span>
</p>
</div>'

Comment: I want to select 'ABC' or 'XYZ'.

Comment: I have clicked the ticked mark.(It has now green colour). I hope this is what you mentioned in your last message.